# Can negative numbers be called large?

Tags: word-usage, semantics

I am dealing with an unknown number x. I don't know if x is negative or positive, but I do know that the magnitude is huge.

So, can I say x is large without implying that it is positive?

Comment: I guess you could, but if you don't want to guess, you can say its absolute value is 'large'

Comment: By negative you mean numbers predeced by  a minus sign, like - 500.000, correct?

Comment: Have you checked the definition of *large* ?

Comment: One would normally use "large negative number" or "large in magnitude" or some such, if only to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think it would be misleading (at best) if someone with a balance of negative 1 million dollars were to claim that that meant he had a "large" amount of money.

Comment: There is a mathematical problem here,  which Kris may be hinting at: you can say that one is smaller or larger than another, but there is no such thing as a large number or a small number.  Consequently, there is no point in saying a positive number is arbitrarily small or that it is a small probability.

Comment: -1000V would be a *high* voltage , and a *large* voltage difference from ground. -$100000 dollars on an account would be a large deficit.

Comment: Julian, I suggest you revert AndyT's edit. The question was fine as it was, and the edit is detrimental. Never mind the closevoters. A dictionary definition of 'large' is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While *large* would technically be applicable to a negative number, the reader could easily mis-interpret it. The 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_numbers) definition, while imperfect, states the following:

> The term typically refers to large positive integers, or more generally, large positive real numbers, but it may also be used in other contexts.

I would suggest, to avoid any kind of confusion, to use one of the followings :

1. The *absolute value* of x is large
2. x's *magnitude* is large
3. x's is a number of *order 10ⁿ*

Comment: The Wikipedia definition perfectly sums up the imperfect usages involved. They can hardly be blamed if the facts are not as might be  wished.

Comment: I do agree and there is no blame on them. I consider the Wikipedia definition to be a good representation of what the average reader of "large number" would understand : not perfect from a rigourous point of view, but helpful in this particular case.

Comment: 4. "x is large and negative"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - The OP states that they do not know whether the number is positive or negative; they want something that will apply equally well for either.

Comment: @AndyT: Oh yes good point

Comment: In the end, simply saying "x is large" would imply to most people that it is of large magnitude and positive. Just qualifying that it is of large magnitude as you did your question perfectly describes that particular aspect of x.

Comment: If there's little chance of reader confusion, then I think "large" is fine.

E.g. "X is a large negative number."

Comment: What about if I want to explicitly refer to positive numbers? Perhaps "X is a high number" or "X is a higher number than Y"? Or maybe "bigger"?

Answer (score 6):

-- Can I say x is large without implying that it has to be positive?

**No.** By saying that *x* is large you do not imply (in the mathematical sense) that it has to be positive, but it may still be understood that way. If you want to convey that *x* is an integer of large magnitude (as I understand it), then it is not safe to just say that *x* is large, because a *large number* of people in the audience will *implicitly* assume *x* is a natural number (a cardinal). Many of the others will not make this assumption. [This post](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/102351/105642), with its diverse answers, exemplifies the problem quite well.

However, it is quite possible that you will be able to convey elsewhere in the text that *x* need not be positive, and this will caution your audience not to make the assumption.

The answer to the question in the title is **yes**, by the way. Negative numbers can still be called large without qualms. However, just saying 'large number' is not a safe way of rendering a number of large magnitude without knowing whether it is positive.

Comment: Presumably by "_a large number of people in the audience_" you mean a negative audience :-)  Seriously (to OP), unless you _knew_ your audience to be mathematically literate, I'd use something like "_a large (positive or negative) number_", or "_a large magnitude number_".

Comment: What about if I want to explicitly refer to positive numbers? Perhaps "X is a high number" or "X is a higher number than Y"? Or maybe "bigger"?

Answer (score 1):

If you take the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value), or modulus, of a number, it becomes real and positive.

In this sense, a negative (or complex) number may be called 'large'.

If we consider a real-world example, you might say a country has a 'large' debt.

Comment: Yes, but the amount of a debt is not by definition a "negative" number. You have 3 billions debt, not  -3 billions debt.

Comment: @JOSH You are right. A better example might be current account balance. Is -1,00,000$ a large current account balance.

Comment: write it as (debt) 3Billion - 'debt' pseud's as a negative sign @JOSH

Comment: Let a be a real number. If a=0, |a|= a. If not, |a| is defined as the larger of a and -a. Thus, if you take the absolute value of a, a does not become a real number, it already is a real number, and |a| might be 0, which is not a positive number. I think people would really object to calling a complex number "large,"  because it is important in complex analysis to understand that there is no mathematically sensible way to provide order to the complex numbers. At least with real numbers one can say  one number is larger than another, even though it makes no sense to say 9798789.8974 is large.

Comment: @Airymouse; you can imbue $\mathbb{C}$ with an order - if z=e^i\theta, order by r then theta, but thats a nother storie

Answer (score -3):

When talking about a "large number", think about it this way:

Replace "number" with "word".  Now suppose you said "I have a large word".  You would think about the length of the word correct?

So, when you say you have a "large number", in this case, I think you are talking about the **length** of the number.  Correct?  So in this case, adding the "-" just makes the number even larger.

So in conclusion, **yes**, you can use the word large, and it can still be negative.

Maybe you should just say "x is a long number"...

**UPDATE**

The OP was referring to saying a "large number":

> So, can I say x is large without implying that it has to be positive?

So, **saying** "*negative* one million, three thousand, four hundred" IS larger than **saying** "one million, three thousand, four hundred."

And when referring to saying a large number, I assumed the litteral length.

Comment: A word cannot have a negative length. Further, numbers can refer to dimensions other than length. Further, adding "-" doesn't make a number larger. This is a very poor answer, showing no understanding of mathematics. I hope you don't find *my* downvote to be random.

Comment: @AndyT I think the point is the length of the number e.g. -10000000 when written out is 'large'.  While not the best answer IMO, It makes sense.

Comment: Sorry but this is nonsense to me. We're not talking about by-symbol length like programmers may treat a string. I think your answer deserves a downvote.

Comment: @AndyT Makes sense.  See update.